# What is the tag [mpu] really made for?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-disambiguation

I stumbled over the tag "mpu" while implementing memory protection and I am not sure for what kind of problem it is made because there is no description for it.

Many questions are depending the usage of "motion processing units" but others are related to the ARM "memory protection unit".

While most of the questions are related to the motion processing units I would suggest writing a tag description for this topic. But I don't know if "mpu" is a common abbreviation for "motion processing unit". However, I would like to see a second tag which refers to memory protection units.

Comment: To be along all other TLA that DMS being abbreviated.

Comment: It was created by, and used by, programmers that have MPU questions.  The primary tag disambiguates, [arduino] for motion and an [arm] related tag for memory.  It is a very small tag so overlap is unlikely to be a problem.